# How to revert to old google adsense interface

Tags: google-adsense

I went into adsense today with my usual opera browser. Things were good until I saw this new blue pop-up with a white box that showed "take a look". I clicked on it and it showed a new page with an error message in the background and in the foreground an orange box. I switched to firefox, and more things came up but the side panel contained no text.

Now I want to revert to the old adsense so I can access all my settings without trying to figure out each word.

Is there a way to revert it?

Comment: Not sure, but... whenever Google introduce a new interface they will often offer a "preview" ("try it now", "take a look", ...) before introducing the change globally. Sometimes you can revert back to the original. However, this is often only delaying the inevitable (unfortunately).

Comment: Hey Mike! It is good to see you. Where have you been? I thought Google may have locked you into a Gulag in Siberia somewhere. :-) Usually there is a small link often off to the side or on the bottom. I have even seen them on the top in a corner. Specifically, I have no idea. Let us know if/where you find one. Cheers Mate!!

Comment: I did but I think its only temporary. In the side bar it looks sort-of like a notepad with a pencil in it. I've been gone because now I'm doing electronic projects and not so much of web development now but in the future I may jump back in.

Comment: @Mike Well come back when you can. You keep us thinking! Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now it is possible to revert.   Click on the hamburger menu (top left) and then  at the bottom of the menu there is "Back to previous AdSense".  At some point Google will force you to use the new only.

[image]

Google designed the new AdSense interface according to [material design](https://material.google.com/) principles.

On the plus side, the new interface is much better on mobile devices. I like the feature on the home page where you can hide the info you don't want to see on a daily basis.

I don't like several things about it:  They recently change the homepage numbers to be like "8.19K" impressions which I find hard to digest.   They also took away the 28 day comparison which is the thing I look at most frequently.

Comment: They sure don't think about people with older browsers. They need to understand www = world wide web, not just web for the rich and nothing for the poor with old computers.

Comment: Maybe you can use some of your AdSense earnings to upgrade.  ;-)

Comment: They are actively working on this.   I've been able to preview this new interface for several months now.  It has gone through many updates, and they are still working on it.   They are paying attention to feedback.   If it isn't working well in your browser, send feedback when you revert back.

Comment: even after reverting back I still cant send feedback. The page just goes dim and nothing pops up.

Comment: What browser are you using, anyway?

Comment: opera 11.62 for linux. I also use firefox 18.